Linux homelab - wiped the Ubuntu OS by accident
(My question got closed on servervault due to it being a home server, and was advised to ask here)
I have a homelab which is a HP Proliant 9 and had Ubuntu 18.04 server installed. I had software installed on top of this to create lab topologies. Ironically I was backing up files to a USB, and I wanted to move all files on the top level of my USB to another folder on the USB. I made a noobie mistake and entered 'mv /* /usb/backup'. I realised very quickly that this has wiped my OS, as well as the contents of the USB. It seems it tried to move the whole OS onto the USB folder. There were no commands available after entering this command, even 'shutdown' wasn't there and the USB showed empty so I powered off the server. Luckily I have some other backups of my files. Today I powered it on and have the grub screen. I do not have detailed knowledge of what I have done or what the damage is. I do not have detailed knowledge of the inner workings of Linux like partitions etc or what I need to do from here. Can I just somehow reinstall Ubuntu server from Grub, and everything will be fine? Or is there remnants of the old OS or other 'gotchas' still there that I need to handle first? Thanks for any help.
Update-> from grub when I do ls, I can see (proc) (memdisk) (hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
When I do ls (hd0,1) I see efi/
When I do ls (hd0,2) I see the folder /usb/backup and inside this folder are the system files I thought were gone! Maybe they can be recovered. I must not have even been copying to the usb.
In this folder I can see initrd.img and vmlinuz. Does that mean I can move them somewhere and then recover the system? How to do that from grub?
I see in another article to do 'initrd (hd0,2)/initrd.img' then 'boot'. But I assume I shouldn't run this from a weird directory such as where I see them now, /usb/backup. For me currently it would be 'initrd (hd0,2)/usb/backup/initrd.img'. Any idea how to proceed?

It sounds like you did not have the USB disk mounted at /usb during that time. Reboot into any kind of Linux "live CD", mount the system partition on /mnt or similar, then mv everything back into the root of that partition (e.g. mv -v /mnt/usb/backup/* /mnt). You probably won't be able to do this from within GRUB as its filesystem support is largely read-only.
If the root filesystem had been completely emptied, then you would have had to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch (the only leftovers being GRUB itself). Of course, files can be moved back from the USB stick, but if it was formatted using FAT or something else that doesn't preserve Linux file permissions by default, then getting those right again would take more time than just reinstalling (and restoring only the configs you need).

So I should use something like 'https://rufus.ie/en/' to create the live usb with Ubuntu server 18.04. When I reboot the server I should be able to see the command line for the usb operating system and then should be able to move the files from the /usb/backup folder. Is all that correct? When you say mv to /mnt, why am I moving to /mnt and not to the root folder? Such as mv -v /mnt/usb/backup/* /?


Rufus will work, yes. 2) Because at that moment, the root folder is the USB operating system's root folder. Your installed system's root would therefore need to be mounted elsewhere, in this example at /mnt. Note how you're also moving from /mnt/usb as well, rather than just from /usb . (In general terms, the "root" isn't inherent to the disk or filesystem or installation, just like on Windows the C: disk would no longer be called C: once it's connected to a different system.)


I'll try this in the coming days when I get time and see how it goes. Thanks.
